# Partial Update option is not visible in the browsable api window

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

[image: Browsable API window]

I have created the update class for put and patch operation and configured in urls too. But the only put button is visible here. The patch button is not available.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from restapp.models import employee
from restapp.serializers import EmployeeSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.generics import UpdateAPIView
class EmployeeUpdateAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset=employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class=EmployeeSerializer
    lookup_field='id'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,re_path
from restapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('api/(?P<pk>\d+)/',views.EmployeeUpdateAPIView.as_view())
]
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from restapp.models import employee

class EmployeeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=employee
        fields='__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class employee(models.Model):
    eno = models.IntegerField()
    ename = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    esal = models.FloatField()
    eaddr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Can you share your `EmployeeSerializer`?

Comment: I have shared serializers.py and models.py in the main code only. Recently edited

Comment: What if you make the fields `required=False`.

Comment: In serializers.py? Or models.py?

Comment: the serializer fields.

Comment: _code please_..

Comment: DRF form doesn't support ***partial update*** operation @BituBrusters

Comment: Are you sure? Because patch action has already been allowed. Just check the screenshot I have shared.

Answer (score 3):

The "PATCH" button is available in the "Raw data" tab:

[image]